# MySQL delete data from 5 tables by JOINING them all together

Tags: php, join, mysqli

I'd like to know if it's possible to delete a data by joining 5 tables. I have 5 tables namely **tbl1, tbl2, tbl3, tbl4, tbl5** and they all of a column named **transaction_id**. is it possible to delete their data by JOIN queries?

Comment: Why don't you try?

Comment: I'm sorry sir. I don't really have an idea on how to do it. i hope you can help me on how to do it.

Comment: http://www.tech-recipes.com/rx/56823/delete-update-rows-using-inner-join-sql-server/

Comment: You have far too many unclosed questions and were told how to accept solutions.

Comment: how can i accept answers?

Comment: @DainisAbols i am still confused sir on how to perform DELETE by JOINING 5 tables. i already have an idea for 2 tables though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it with joins but joins will complicate the process.

ex:
DELETE table1, table2, table3 FROM table1 INNER JOIN table2 INNER JOIN table3 WHERE table1.userid = table2.userid AND table2.userid = table3.userid AND table1.userid=3

another way of doing this is you can define foreign key constraints on the tables with ON DELETE CASCADE option.Then deleting the record from parent table removes the records from child tables.

for ref :https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/innodb-foreign-key-constraints.html#innodb-foreign-key-definitions

Answer (score 0):

Try this one,

```
DELETE FROM tbl1 
USING tbl1, tbl2,tbl3,tbl4,tbl5
WHERE tbl1.transaction_id = tbl2.transaction_id AND tbl3.transaction_id = tbl1.transaction_id AND tbl4.transaction_id = tbl1.transaction_id AND tbl5.transaction_id = tbl1.transaction_id AND WHERE tab1.transaction_id = yourid;
```